# Default value for intrinsic attributes

Tags: reactjs

In my react app i have something like this:

```
export const MyView(props: { var1: boolean, var2: string}) => { /* do things here */ }

class MyClass extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        // ...
        <MyView var1={ true } var2={ "test" }/>
    }
}
```

which is working fine. Now, i do not need the var1 param each time i use MyView. Is there a way to define a default value for var1 in MyView, so that i do not have to set the value each time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` as an optional parameter which will treat as an optional parameter.

```
export const MyView = (props: { var1?: boolean, var2: string }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>var1:{props.var1}</div>
      <div>var2:{props.var2}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Note: after adding this you will have to check if var1 is defined or not, before using it other wise it will give an error.

You can view a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ft13rq)

Comment: Thanks alot. This is working best in my case, although it doesn't set a default value to a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

you can use optional params like this (if you do not pass any params, it will use default as given)

```
export const MyView(props: { var1: boolean, var2: string} = {var1:"default_value", var2: null}) => { /* do things here */ }

class MyClass extends React.Component<MyProps, {}> {
    render() {
        // ...
        <MyView var1={ true } var2={ "test" }/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to set default values. I'm new to react and this was a completely new thing for me